# spring sample application in netbeans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans

This is my code. I have gotten some errors. Can anyone help me solve the problem? I get some casting errors, like cast `ClassPathResource` to `Resource` and resource object `r` to resource.

```
package firstspring;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args){

Resource r =new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");


BeanFactory bf=new XmlBeanFactory(r);

Student stud=(Student)bf.getBean("first");

stud.display();

} 

}
```

This is my XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans 

xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="first" class="Student">

<property name="name" value="sneha"></property>    

</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: _it shows some errors_ what all those errors?

Comment: Format your question to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: @PradeepSimha error is to cast classpathresorce to cast..

Comment: where have u declared eResource, or is it some in-built class , if yes.. u are missing the import.

Comment: `eResource` seems to be a typo. It should be `Resource`.

Comment: @R.J  it is  my mistake. am editted then please look

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using both the resources like `javax.annotation.Resource` and `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`, which has resulted in a conflict.

You need to use them like this

```
org.springframework.core.io.Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
```

then program will execute.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist:what i do?

Comment: make sure if u r using standalone java program put applicationContext.xml to src folder. or else put in package then code like new ClassPathResource("packagename/Applicationcontext.xml");

Comment: that is solved..then came another problem :org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [Student] for bean with name 'first' defined in class path resource [firstspring/applicationContext.xml];

Comment: @R.J  :org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [Student] for bean with name 'first' defined in class path resource [firstspring/applicationContext.xml]; –

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing

```
javax.annotation.Resource
```

use,

```
org.springframework.core.io.Resource
```