# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException while I am doing a sample project I spring

Tags: java, spring

There is some error while I am doing a sample project in spring..the error is like this...Test.java, applicationContext.java,Student.java this files are in src folder....

```
Oct 29, 2013 11:37:15 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@e458c2: startup date [Tue Oct 29 11:37:15 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 29, 2013 11:37:15 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at springapplication.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second).......
       My code is this...
       Test.java

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationConteXt.xml");
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
    Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");
    student.displayinfo();
 }

}
```

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist` ... I guess that's obvious enough

Comment: I'm sure I saw a very similar question to this just a while back, but from another account. Ah, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650110/spring-sample-application-in-netbeans). See if this helps you.

Comment: your beans.xml is not in classpath I think you are following some tutorial paste the link to that

Comment: @R.J I used that, but it didn't work...

Comment: I don't get it. In your `Test` class, you load the *applicationConteXt.xml* file but the error says unable to find the *beans.xml* file. What is exact name of the `xml` you're trying to load?!

Comment: @R.J my file is applicationContext.xml...

Answer (score 4):

You gotta put it in `resources` directory of maven project. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

With my Eclipse Java project, I fixed it by making the folder above the relative path a source folder.

Answer (score 1):

beans.xml inside "com/mypackage" (Ex: com\mypackage\beans.xml);

How I was using

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml"); ----> ERROR.
```

There are three solutions:

1. Take the beans.xml out of package and put in **default package name**.

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( com/**default package name**/beans.xml);
```

2. if you put bean.xml inside mypackage(Package that contains your java files).

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/mypackage/beans.xml");
```

3. We can put `beans.xml` inside `ProjectName\src`

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

your applicationContext.xml is not in class path like not in src(source) folder of project. place your applicationContext.xml in src folder.
this will work

Comment: applicationContext.xml ,student.java,Test.java...this all are in src folder..All this files are already in src folder.

Comment: can u provide me application context.xml file content and which type of jar(spring) version u r using.

Comment: jar file is ,Spring Framework 3.1.1.RELEASE....This is applicationContext.xml<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="studentbean" class="com.javatpoint.Student">
        <property name="name" value="Babitha Baby"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>

Comment: provide http url for schema location here is code add into your beans tag and remove existing.  like xmlns="http://www.springframework.gor/schema/beans <beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"> this will work

Answer (score 0):

**solution which worked for me**

**first point - where spring.xml file should be placed**

- created new directory under src/main named resources
- created    spring.xml file under resources directory

can refer screenshot attached below
[image]
**second thing : spring.xml file code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <bean id="vehicle" class="org.example.Car"></bean>
</beans>
```

in place of defining bean definition in beans tag you may also use DOCTYPE, then spring.xml will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="vehicle" class="org.example.Car"></bean>
</beans>
```

**lastly : how to call spring.xml file from main method**
can refer below screenshot
[image]

*hope it solved your problem, cheers :)*